# Windows Server 2008 - Calling FTP from .CMD - Pass a parameter to an FTP file?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ftp, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I am calling the following from a .cmd file:

```
 ftp -d -s:D:\backup\web-daily.txt
```

The web-daily.txt file is an ftp input file with similar contents to this:

```
open <server>
<login>
<password>
put d:\backup\web-daily.7z web-daily.7z
quit
```

I need to be able to pass the current date to the ftp input file. Is this doable without having to execute a program that actually modifies web-daily.txt? This is because web-daily.7z is actually web-daily_%date:~10,4%*%date:~4,2%*%date:~7,2%.7z (or web-daily_yyyy_MM_dd.7z).

I'd like to pass this date in as a parameter if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this will do it, in North American format. There may be a way to make it universal, but that may not be important if the server won't change.

```
@echo off
setlocal

@echo off > %0.ftp
>> %0.ftp echo open <server>
>> %0.ftp echo <user>
>> %0.ftp echo <pw>
>> %0.ftp echo put d:\backup\web-daily_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z web-daily_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z
>> %0.ftp echo quit

ftp -s:%0.ftp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to effectively pass a date parameter to an FTP input file on windows.

```
@echo off
setlocal

@echo off > %0.ftp
>> %0.ftp echo open <server>
>> %0.ftp echo <user>
>> %0.ftp echo <pw>
>> %0.ftp echo put d:\backup\web-daily_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z web-daily_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.7z
>> %0.ftp echo quit

ftp -s:%0.ftp
```

This will send web-daily_yyyy_mm_dd.7z to the ftp server.

Comment: Only works in your locale. For me `_-0_-2` is inserted in place of the date. Be very careful with dates in batch files.

Comment: Does %date% give you something more meaningful? It may have to be parsed differently.

Answer (score -2):

```
Rem: This worked for me

@echo off
setlocal

@echo off > %0.ftp
>> %0.ftp echo open **server**
>> %0.ftp echo **userid**
>> %0.ftp echo **password**
>> %0.ftp hash
>> %0.ftp asc
>> %0.ftp echo lcd c:\program\data\ (your local path)
>> %0.ftp echo cd fam/user/tcs/in/hold (your ftp path)
>> %0.ftp echo get 01000%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%01.txt
>> %0.ftp echo quit

ftp -s:%0.ftp
del %0.ftp

rem below line gets a file with today's date from the ftp server
01000%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%01.txt
```